# quarkus container with state hangs on Apple M1

Tags: docker, performance, keycloak, quarkus, apple-m1

I am building a quarkus (Keycloak 18) based container on the following way:

1. Start a container from this image `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0`
2. Fill the running container with state (users, roles, clients using terraform)
3. Commit the running container with `docker commit running-container my-filled-keycloak-image`
4. The whole process is running in a Github action pipeline

The image can be used on a regular basis and runs quite normal. Only users of an Apple M1 seem to have problem with this image. In most cases starting a container simply gets stuck and hangs until a docker timeout occurs. Sometimes the container is able to start, but on very low performance and very slow.

The problem seems to be related to the Apple M1 architecture and up to now we do not have an idea how to fix this. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you build multiarch image? E.g. `linux/arm64` architecture for M1?

Comment: Hi @JanGaraj, I am simply running docker commit on my ci service. Do I need to specify some arguments when committing the running container into an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are building images on your CI, which is running on `amd64` (Intel) architecture. Unfortunately, this architecture is not natively supported on M1, which uses `arm64`. So your users with M1 use emulation (search `Rosetta`, which is not a perfect). The better option is to build multiarch image (image, which contains `amd64,arm64,...` architectures), so users will use native architecture on their machines.

There is a lot of resources how to build multiarch (multiplatform) Docker images. Random one: https://jitsu.com/blog/multi-platform-docker-builds

Comment: Do you know if there is also a way to build an multiarch image using the `docker commit `command? I could not find any infos on this.

Comment: I would say no directly. I guess you can commit images on each architecture separatly and then somehow combine them into single multiarch image.